# Adding an instance variable using enumerable#map returns wrong information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I'm currently working on a Rails/Mapbox app. I currently am not storing geolocation for my `House` object, and rather am using a helper method to create a temporary instance variable to store geolocation to pass to Mapbox.

Below, `all_houses` argument is an array of many `House` objects.

I created the following helper method:

```
def add_geolocation(all_houses)
  all_houses.map do |house|
    house_geo = find_geolocation(house.address)

    class << house
      attr_accessor :geo
    end

    house.geo = house_geo
  end
end
```

I'm using the Gon Gem to pass this information from my controller to Mapbox. What is being returned is an array of arrays with only geolocations stored for each house. What I am trying to do is pass every instance variable stored for the each `House` object and also pass its geolocation.

Also, to add, I have also tried the Ruby method Object#set_instance_variable and I am getting the same result.

What I want:

```
[<House:0x007fe5670d9cc0 @a="a", @b="b", @geo=[10, 10]>, <House:0x007fe5670d9cc0 @a="a", @b="b", @geo=[10, 11]>, <House:0x007fe5670d9cc0 @a="a", @b="b", @geo=[12, -12]>, ...]
```

What I am getting is an Array of Arrays with only geolocations, for example:

```
[[10, 10], [10, 11], [12, -12] ...]
```

Edit:

Below is what I have in my controller. `gon` is from the Gon Gem

```
def index
  @houses = House.all
  json_houses = add_geolocation(House.all)

  gon.houses = json_houses
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `map`, the last line of the block is the implicit return statement from which the new array is constructed.  To return the modified house objects, `house` needs to be the return

```
def add_geolocation(all_houses)
  all_houses.map do |house|
    house_geo = find_geolocation(house.address)

    class << house
      attr_accessor :geo
    end

    house.geo = house_geo
    house
  end
end
```

Edit: You may need something like this in your controller method

```
def index
  @houses = House.all
  json_houses = add_geolocation(House.all)

  gon.houses = json_houses.as_json(methods: %i(geo))
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried returning house within the `map` block and am now getting returned all `House` objects in an array without a `geo` attribute inside.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `gon` gem, but I suspect what is happening is that it's serializing your model using `to_json`, which will unfortunately leave out those variables which are added to a model dynamically.  Instead, you can use `as_json` to specify that this additional attribute should also be included.  I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Ben, that solution works and is passing all information